# Total number of factors of a number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Can you please explain how can we derive the total number of factors of a composite number using the concept of combinations ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should search for "number of factors"  or "divisor function"  on this site.  It brings up many hits.  The  [Wikipedia page on the divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) covers this well.

Answer (score 5):

A composite number $n$ can be written as $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$. The number of factors of $n$ is the product of the number of factors of $p_i^{a_i}$ for each $i=1,\ldots,k$. (This is because it is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)) It is easy to count the factors of $p^a$: they are simply the powers $p^0,p^1,\ldots,p^a$. Thus, there are $a+1$ such factors.

Applying this for each value of $i$, we have that the number of factors of $n$ is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(a_i+1)$.

---

To see this using a more combinatorial viewpoint, consider that a factor of $n$ is a number of the form $d=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}$, where each $b_i$ satisfies $0\le b_i\le a_i$. Thus, we have $a_i+1$ choices for each $b_i$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, every natural is the product of primes with a certain multiplicity.

Then every factor of the initial number is a product of the same primes with a (possibly) lower multiplicity.

Hence you need to form all combinations of the possible multiplicities.

---

$$360=2^33^25^1\to000,100,200,300,010,110,210,310,020,120,220,320,001,101,201,301,011,111,211,311,021,121,221,321$$

$(3+1)\cdot(2+1)\cdot(1+1)$ of them.

Comment: Thank you ! But I was wondering whether $000$ would really be included in this ?

Comment: @AditiParetkar: review your definition of the factors.

Comment: Indeed, 000 represents the number 1, which is a factor of any integer.